# Retrieving custom text from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, text, fonts, get

I have a self-made blog where I post articles. I store the articles in a db (mysql) , and from time to time I like to edit the articles.

Whenever I run this code (in my edit page) , I only retrieve the text in simple form (no font , no colour , no nothing) , just the basic text :

```
<form method="post" action="edit_script.php">

Title:<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>"><br>
Body:<br><input name="body" value="<?php echo $body; ?>">

<script>CKEDITOR.replace( 'body' );</script> (<-this is the rich text editor I use)

<input type="hidden"  name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and whenever I edit it , I add a word with font-size 14 for example , it shows up on the main page just like the other words , all in the same font.

This is the main page code (the one where I display the text from the db after it's been written || Basically same code) :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
echo "<h1>" . $row['title'] . "</h1>";
echo $row['body'];
echo "<h6>" . $row['data'] . "</h6>";
}
```

Again , text shows up , its just not customised (edited etc.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the original text being stored as html with all the formatting ?

Comment: yes , for example I am trying to write "Filip" in purple , the text in the database is : "<p><strong><span style="color:#4B0082"><span style="font-size:18px">FILIP</span></span></strong></p>"
It just doesn't get outputted

Comment: My first idea would be to use <textarea> instead of an <input> field.

Comment: Yeah , sorry , should have mentioned , I did change it to a <textarea> which I replaced with a CKEditor rich-text editor and it still won't show up customised

Comment: This is quite strange. Where does the $body variable come from ? Maybe something's doing strip_tags() on you.

Comment: On the main page , where I want to display the text , I just have this :

   
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
 echo "<h1>" . $row['title'] . "</h1>";
 echo $row['body'];
    }
    and a bit of other php but no defining variables 


In the edit page :

$body = $_POST['body'];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
 $title = $row['title'];
 $body = $row['body'];
 
}

Comment: and the edit page utilises the same query but with "where id=123" yeah ? or is there anything else that manipulates the data ?

Comment: This is the query for both pages : $query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER by id desc";

Comment: Ok one more question. When you view the page source, is the formatting present in the <textarea> ?